# CloudFirestore Recyclerview kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I'm new to cloudfirestore and when I'm trying to add the firebaseui recycler view the app crashes and gives new kotlinnullpoint exception...I followed the instructions created the adapter and then query etc but still, it's crashing.
here' all take a look.

```
class LocationFragment : Fragment() {

    @BindView(R.id.progress_bar)
    @JvmField
    internal var progressBar: ProgressBar? = null
    @BindView(R.id.loc_list)
    @JvmField
    internal var  locList: RecyclerView? = null
    private var db: FirebaseFirestore? = null
    private var adapter: FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<LocationResponse, LocationListHolder>? = null
    internal var linearLayoutManager: LinearLayoutManager? = null

    private val callback = OnMapReadyCallback { googleMap ->
        /**
         * Manipulates the map once available.
         * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
         * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera.
         * In this case, we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
         * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to
         * install it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the
         * user has installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
         */
        val home = LatLng(17.4397148, 78.4941421)
        googleMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(home).title("Church Home"))
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(home))
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.con_location, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment?
        mapFragment?.getMapAsync(callback)
        init()
        getLocationList()

    }

    private fun init() {
        linearLayoutManager =
            LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        locList?.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    }

    private fun getLocationList() {
        val query: Query = db!!.collection("locations")
        val response: FirestoreRecyclerOptions<LocationResponse> = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<LocationResponse>()
            .setQuery(query, LocationResponse::class.java)
            .build()

        //val options = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<LocationResponse>().setQuery(query, LocationResponse::class.java).build()
        adapter = object : FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<LocationResponse, LocationListHolder>(response) {
            override fun onBindViewHolder(
                holder: LocationListHolder,
                position: Int,
                model: LocationResponse
            ) {
                progressBar!!.visibility = View.GONE
                holder.textName!!.setText(model.location_title)
                holder.textTitle!!.setText(model.location_address)
                /*holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { v: View? ->
                    Snackbar.make(
                        friendList,
                        model.getName().toString() + ", " + model.getTitle() + " at " + model.getCompany(),
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
                    )
                        .setAction("Action", null).show()
                }*/
            }

            override fun onCreateViewHolder(group: ViewGroup, i: Int): LocationListHolder {
                val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(group.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_location, group, false)
                return LocationListHolder(view)
            }

            override fun onError(e: FirebaseFirestoreException) {
                Log.e("error", e.message)
            }
        }
        adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
        locList!!.adapter = adapter
    }

    inner class LocationListHolder(itemView: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView!!) {
        @BindView(R.id.loct)
        @JvmField
        var textName: TextView? = null
        @BindView(R.id.locaddr)
        @JvmField
        var textTitle: TextView? = null

        init {
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView!!)
        }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        adapter!!.startListening()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        adapter!!.stopListening()
    }
}
```

- Model class

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
class LocationResponse {

    constructor() {}
    constructor(location_title: String?, location_address: String?) {
        this.location_title = location_title
        this.location_address = location_address
    }

    var location_title: String? = null
    var location_address: String? = null
}
```

- con_locations.xml

  ```
  <include
      android:id="@+id/include"
      layout="@layout/fragment_location"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  <ProgressBar
      android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include" />

  <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/loc_list"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:divider="#00000000"
      android:layout_margin="8dp"
      tools:listitem="@layout/item_location"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include" />
  ```
- Logcat

```
    2019-11-29 20:13:26.116 30744-30755/download.crossally.apps.tktchurch I/.apps.tktchurc: Background young concurrent copying GC freed 5547(805KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 19% free, 2860KB/3550KB, paused 679us total 179.439ms
        2019-11-29 20:13:26.239 30744-30744/download.crossally.apps.tktchurch D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
        2019-11-29 20:13:26.240 30744-30744/download.crossally.apps.tktchurch E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
            Process: download.crossally.apps.tktchurch, PID: 30744
            kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
                at download.crossally.apps.tktchurch.ui.location.LocationFragment.getLocationList(LocationFragment.kt:119)
                at download.crossally.apps.tktchurch.ui.location.LocationFragment.onViewCreated(LocationFragment.kt:71)
                at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:892)
                at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2100)
                at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1874)
                at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1830)
                at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
                at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Here's the logcat

Comment: paste the logcat error too

Comment: I have added the logcat please take a look.

Comment: 119 th line in LocationFragment causes error. Which is that line?

Comment: `locList!!.adapter = adapter`